# Android Facebook API - example

Tags: android, facebook

I would like to develop and application which post a link on a wall of the use
i followed this [Android Tutorial Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/)

But i failed to run the application because 
Step 4: Add reference to the Facebook SDK fails i can't add Facebook library
I tried to Use Android 3.0 API + Eclipse 
Is there other tutorial i can use please post links
Regards

Comment: please give details on what error you are seeing.

Comment: Try using EasyFacebookAndroidSDK. It's easy to implement. Here, I found out a good tutorial about it [http://kodefun.junian.net/2011/10/easy-facebook-android-sdk-simple.html](http://kodefun.junian.net/2011/10/easy-facebook-android-sdk-simple.html)

Answer (score 4):

To use facebook as a library, you not only need to add facebook project to

project property > android > library,

but also ned to add facebook project to

project property > Java build path > projects > add.

I believe facebook tutorial skipped adding facebook project to java build path

somehow and that made me search a solution for long hours.

Hope this is your case too. good luck

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you are not able to add facebook sdk library to your project because you might have not imported the project into your workspace (check the box "copy to workspace") when importing facebookSDK project.

Steps to add library to your project
1.Go to your project properties 
2.click Android tab in the window which opens
3.scroll down you will see an option to add library click "add" and then select facebookSdk project